# Hovering effect not working when link is active

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

hei everyone :) so i'm making this menu and everything works perfectly until i make a new site  for when you click on the links. then the links get active and when i then hover over the link. and it's  supposed to get the background color and text color it get's when you hovering. it doesn't seem to work.

the background color still get's the same, but the text color just remain black instead of changing. and if i change the color on the text when you make it active, then the text will remain that color even if i'm not hovering. and it's only supposed to change when it's hovering.

my menu code in css:

```
.link{
float:left; 
text-decoration:none; 
color:#000000;
font-size:19px;
background:opacity:0.4;
width:130px;
padding-bottom:8px;
padding-top:8px;
padding-right:25px;
text-align:left;
padding-left:8px;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
border-top:1px solid black;
color:black;
line-height:1.5;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:left;

-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;  
}

a:link:hover
{
background-color:black;
color:#18ffec;}
```

relevant code in html:

```
<div id="linki">

<p>

<a class="link" href="Index.html"> Hjem</a>
<a class="link" href="Guider.html"> Guider</a>
<a class="link" href="Om_oss.html"> Om oss</a>
<a class="link" href="Kontakt.html"> Kontakt oss</a>
<a class="link" href="Hjelp til"> Hjelp til </a>

</p>
</div>
```

appreciate any answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying the class wrong, use a "." instead of a ":"

a.link:hover

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean

```
a.link:hover
```

rather than

```
a:link:hover
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use class name:

```
.link:hover
{
   background-color:black;
   color:#18ffec;
}
```

`:link` is a "a normal, unvisited link" so when it's visited the hover will not work. There is no need for `a.link` you can use just class name in this case.